# Should the company name or the service type be better in local franchise domain name for SEO?

Tags: seo, domains, google-search, domain-registration

I am building a website for a business that is a franchise of a bigger business.  A lot of franchises use `CompanyNameCityLocation.TLD` to register their domains and often are number 1 in a relatively, albeit local, highly competitive market.

However, when I did a former site for another franchise, `ServiceTypeofBusinessCityName.TLD` would always out rank `CompanyNameCityname.TLD`.  Also, "Service Name" is the store sign of the physical location.

Now with this new school/franchise we have the opportunity to get the domain `ServiceTypeofBusinessCityName.TLD` (which is difficult).  Do you think this would be the best name for SEO AND local students to find the business?  Another idea was`ServiceTypeofBusinessCityNameCompanyName.TLD`, or is sticking to the "brand" approach the best bet with `CompanyNameCityname.TLD`?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on whether or not the brand gets more search than the actual service. In most cases the service is probably most the larger volume.

I think it makes sense to use both domains and 301 the service to the brand if it has already been indexed. You should be able to get most of the keyword power in the redirected domain while reinforcing your brand in links and advertising.

Comment: Adding domain names to a single site does nothing but waste money. Using 301 redirect from a domain name renders that domain name useless. Otherwise, you are correct about people searching for a service more times than not. Short of a specific brand search such as Sears, most people would simply search appliance repair.

Comment: Thank you.  First paragraph of reply makes sense.  Glad comment confirms service vs brand in this situation.  Second paragraph I have been told can hurt SEO.  Up voted comment and reply.

Comment: 301 redirects do pass on links and keyword relevance, it is losing effectiveness, but it's still widely used and sometimes necessary to migrate domains. It can be interpreted as spam if you are redirecting to a page instead of the root of the domain or are using several domains. 

You could try to run both domains as their own website, but you need unique content and it may not rank all that well without a Google Business Listing.